# Java best way to select random subset from an array of strings with no duplicates

Tags: java, random, duplicates, subset

Looking for a more efficient way to select a random subset of elements (no duplicates) from an array of strings.

```
public static String randomReturnArray(String inputArray[]) {

    String[] tmpInputArr = Arrays.copyOf(inputArray, inputArray.length);

    Random r = new Random();
    int inMin = 0;
    int inMax = inputArray.length;
    int numOfMarkings = r.nextInt((inMax - inMin) + 1) + inMin;
    int[] arrOfInputIndexes = new int[numOfMarkings];

    for (int d = 0; d < numOfMarkings; d++) {
        Random f = new Random();
        int index = f.nextInt(inputArray.length);
        arrOfInputIndexes[d] = index;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrOfInputIndexes.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arrOfInputIndexes.length; j++) {
            if (arrOfInputIndexes[i] == arrOfInputIndexes[j]) {
                arrOfInputIndexes = ArrayUtils.remove(arrOfInputIndexes, j);
            }
        }
    }

    String[] finalArray = new String[arrOfInputIndexes.length];
    for (int l = 0; l < arrOfInputIndexes.length; l++) {
        int temp = arrOfInputIndexes[l];
        finalArray[l] = tmpInputArr[temp];
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String marking : finalArray) {
        builder.append(marking);
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    String finalArray = builder.toString();

    return finalArray;
}
```

Here the thought process:

1. Create supporting vars - a new array of random length (less than input.length)
2. fill array with random integers
3. remove duplicates
4. grab the values from the input array at the index of the random integers
5. build string and return

Much appreciated.

Comment: If the goal is efficiency, did you consider selecting your N random integers by running the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for just N steps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Collections.shuffle` which is exactly for these purposes.

For example:

```java
String[] strings = new String[] {
     "foo", "bar", "toto", "fox", "koukou", "bar", "Bar" 
} ;

// Filter-out duplicates, then shuffle
final List<String> stringsList = Arrays.stream(strings)
    .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(stringsList);
// Take a sample
final int k = 3; // the sample size
List<String> sample = stringsList.subList(0, k); // this is a view, not another list
System.err.println(sample);
```

If we did not care about duplicates, things would be a bit simpler and shuffling could be performed on the original array (then, we could just pick first k elements):

```java
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(strings));
```